# how do I set the alignment of this control in android xml

Tags: android, xml

[image]

In this picture, the left edge of the bottom TextView has becoe aligned with the left edge of the top TextView. This causes the position of the bottom text view to change when the size of the top text view changes during the actual execution of this program, during which time the top text view's width changes multiple times. I want the bottom text view to stay in a fixed position, but cannot find out how to make it's position independent of the top text view. How do I aligh the bottom text view's left edge to, say, the right edge of the Gain text view?

Here's the xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewFreq"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18.0sp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarFreq"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/seekBarGain"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewFreq" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarGain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewGain"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelFrequency"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/seekBarFreq"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewFreq"
        android:textSize="18.0sp"
        android:text="@string/tvFreq" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/seekBarGain"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/seekBarGain"
         android:textSize="18.0sp"
        android:text="@string/tvGain" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewGain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewFreq"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarFreq"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18.0sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Put android_gravity="top" for each TextView. As well as use android:layout_alignParentTop="true", may from these 2 option one will work.

Comment: isn't there anyway in android to set absolute position with respect to the screen edges, or any other custom viewports, as in Visual C++?

Comment: No, you have to set it using xml attributes only. There is lots of attributes to set, please try once as per I given and check if its working or not.

Comment: There is a way, set android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" for the TextViews and it will place them in middle of the screen(absolute position, as the parent view has match parent and occupies the whole screen).. And of course remove android:layout_alignLeft

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewGain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/seekBarGain"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="37dip"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="18.0sp" />
```